# JAXB related exception

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, classcastexception

When I attempt to connect to my web service, which is running on the local machine, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:232)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:460)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:65)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:68)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:557)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:529)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.<clinit>(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:533)
    ... 20 more
```

All the information I've read suggests that this is caused by a conflict between different versions of JAXB. However, it doesn't seem that this is case for me. In the /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext folder I have jaxb-api.jar and jaxb-impl.jar. It doesn't seem that either of these appear more than once. Under "Referenced libraries" in the project, it doesn't seem like any other JAXB stuff is in there.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Here's a list of referenced libraries:

[image]

Comment: There are two JAXBContextImpl, one in rt.jar, another in jaxb-impl.jar, they reside in different packages and I think you somehow mixed them

Comment: I checked my JSE/JRE installations and they don't have jaxb-impl.jar, maybe you have put them there by mistake?